# Can not read data from server using GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: ios, cocoa, networking, gcdasyncsocket

I tried to connect to the server and send some information to the server(like username, password..), and the server send me back the ID (string type). The problem is I can not get the ID. Could anyone help me? I am beginner in IOS coding. Thanks.

Here is the codes:

1. After I click the button, it will call my own function to get serverIP which is a string and Port which is a int.
2. Then that function will call this function to connect the server:

   ```
   (void)logInCheck {

       asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];   
       NSError *error = nil;
       uint16_t port = serverPort;

       if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:serverIP onPort:port error:&error])
       {
           DDLogError(@"Unable to connect to due to invalid configuration: %@", error);
       }
       else
       {
           DDLogVerbose(@"Connecting...");
           [self passDataToServer];
       }
   }

   //DataPassToServer is a NSString that hold my data

   (void)passDataToServer
   {
       NSData *requestData = [DataPassToServer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       [asyncSocket writeData:requestData withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
       [asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
   }

   //this function call successfully

   -(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
   {
       DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", host, port);
   }

   //this function call successfully

   (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
   {
       DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didWriteDataWithTag:");
   }

   //This function does not run !!! Nothing print out. 

   (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
   {
       DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didReadData:withTag:");
       NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"ID = %@",response);
       [asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes it is able to receive. Right now, I can get ID from the server but after that I will disconnect due to this reason: socketDidDisconnect:withError: "Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x68eb130 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}" Do you know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about your server implementation but, most implementations would read up to the first newline character before processing the request.

So make sure that your `[DataPassToServer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` includes a newline character (`"\n"`) at the end.

Your code looks fine and works for me.

Comment: Can I ask you one more? the sever did response to me, but after that it disconnected due to this reason: socketDidDisconnect:withError: "Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x68eb130 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}" Could you tell me why?? Many thanks!

Comment: Well, this seems to be an issue of the server implementation. Is it _your_ server, or a thirt-party server you're trying to communicate with? In order to move on we would need to know a bit more about what your server does, since the connection is clearly closed by the server.